# Firebird, выполнение запроса в триггере от другого пользователя

Tags: sql, firebird

Есть Firebird база, в которой определённая таблица (Т1) заполняется автоматически, при заполнении других таблиц. Хотелось бы назначить права на запись в Т1 пользователю П1 (а остальным только читать); на некоторые таблицы повесить триггер, обновляющий данные в Т1 от пользователя П1.

Как такое сделать в Firebird (желательно версии 2.5) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если отвечать напрямую на вопрос в заголовке, то при помощи `EXECUTE STATEMENT` можно выполнить запрос от имени другого пользователя.

Но мне кажется что вам поможет другая особенность Firebird, а именно раздача прав на таблицу не только пользователям, но также процедурам и триггерам.

Вы можете на свою таблицу `T1` дать всем пользователя только право читать, а триггеру - право писать в нее.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую сделать как Вы предложили.